# Database / ORM modelling of roads between cities

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, relationship, data-modeling

I'm breaking my head over how to model a simple system of cities and roads in a database and ORM (Doctrine, in my case).

In my simplified system, every road connects exactly two cities.

I would like to have every city have a "roads" property, but cannot wrap my head around how to model the inverse side, the road entity. I could probably model it with a many-to-many relationship, but isn't that nonsense when I know that a road will always have exactly two cities? But if I use two many-to-one (cities can have many roads) relationships, I have two properties on the cities as well (incoming and outgoing roads, for example).

I couldn't find a solution in a search, so I'm asking here now.

Comment: Table 1: cities.  Table 2: roads.  In the roads table, you have 2 FK, which are the two end points of the road.  Don't link roads to cities, do it the other way around.

Comment: If I don't link them, I cannot traverse the cities with a "cities->roads" query, or can I? And at the DB-level, I have to double all queries with (A or B)

Comment: Define what queries you need.  Ex. how many roads for 1 city?  `select count(roadid) where city1 = 'Boston' or city2 = 'Boston'`  If you can cover all your query requirements (and I think you can with what I proposed), then you know the model meets your needs.  If you need to know what city the road is from, you can link the cities to roads with names like `StartCity`, `EndCity`.

Comment: as written above: exactly two cities.

I'm now modelling it with a many-to-many relationship, because your solution might work better on direct SQL, but this solution works better in Doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

As Nic said : "Table 1: cities. Table 2: roads. In the roads table, you have 2 FK, which are the two end points of the road. Don't link roads to cities, do it the other way around".

In your alternative, think about how you are going to ***enforce*** that each road indeed has a "city on either side" ???  Foreign keys from your kind of m-n ensure only that it will be a city ***if it has been provided***, not that one ***must*** be provided (let alone that ***two*** must be provided).

ORMs are quite renowned for depriving the user of a lot of the expressive power that SQL does offer them (e.g. good luck doing transitive closures over your ROADS table in your ORM).  If you're in that case, that's a reason for leaving the ORM path and going SQL.  Choose the right tool for the job.

If you're looking at how life can be made the easiest for yourself ("this solution works better in Doctrine") then you're looking from the wrong angle.